# Translations into logical notation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

The question is:

> Let the predicate $L(x,y)$ stand for "$x$ loves $y$", where the
>   universe is the set $\{cat, dog, fish, bird, snake\}$
>
> Translate the following statements into logical notation:
>
> (a) Everyone loves the cat.
>
> (b) No animal loves any animal.
>
> (c) Some animals are not loved by anyone.
>
> (d) Some animals both love and are loved by the cat.
>
> Translate the following from logical notation to English
>
> (e) $\exists x \forall y L(x,y)$

My attempt:

(a) $\forall x (L(x,cat))$

(b) $\neg \exists x (L(x,y))$

(c) $\exists y(\neg L(x,y)$

(d) $\exists x(L(x,cat) \land L(cat,x))$

(e) Some animals love every animal.

I am trying to ensure I understand this topic, so please correct me if my answers are wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: two quantifiers in the English, two quantifiers in the translation. Hence, for example, on the more natural reading,

No animal loves any animal

= (No animal x is such that)(There is some animal y such that) $L(x, y)$

= not(There is some animal x such that)(There is some animal y such that) $L(x, y)$

= $\neg\exists x\exists y\;L(x, y)$

Or, equivalently = $\forall x\neg\exists y\;L(x, y)$

Comment: Thank you! Based on your hint I assume (c) is incorrect as well, and the remaining are correct?

Comment: Check also exactly where brackets should go in your syntax. Compare e.g. your (a) with the question (e).